# Why does Visual Studio 2010 give me a syntax error with this code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
template<typename T>
class nodAB : public arbBinar<T> 
{
private:
    T info;
    nodAB<T> *tata;
    nodAB<T> *st;
    nodAB<T> *dr;

public:
    nodAB(const T& x):info(x),tata(0),st(0),dr(0){};
    nodAB(const T& x, nodAB<T> *t):info(x),tata(t),st(0),dr(0){};

    virtual nodAB<T>* copiaza();
    virtual nodAB<T>*insereaza (T& item);
    virtual void parcurge_invers();
    void setInfo(T& x) {info =x;}
    void setTata(nodAB<T> *t) {tata=t;}
    void setStang(nodAB<T> *stang) {st=stang;}
    void setDrept(nodAB<T> *drept) {dr=drept;}

    T getInfo() const {return info;}
    nodAB<T> *getStang() const {return st;}
    nodAB<T> *getDrept() const {return dr;}
    nodAB<T> *getTata() const {return tata;}

    bool esteRadacina()const
    {
        return tata==NULL;
    }
    bool esteFrunza()const
    {
        return (st==NULL &&  dr==NULL);
    }
    bool esteFiuStang()const
    {
        return tata!=NULL  && tata->getStang()==this;
    }
    bool esteFiuDrept()const
    {
        return tata!=NULL && tata->getDrept()==this;
    }
    ~nodAB();
};
```

My question is why in `class nodAB: public arbBinar<T> {` does Visual Studio give me a syntax error?

```
template<typename T>
class arbBinar{
protected:
    nodAB<T> *radacina;

public:
    arbBinar():radacina(0){}
    arbBinar(nodAB<T> *rad) {radacina=rad;}
    nodAB<T> *getRadacina(){return radacina;}
    ~arbBinar();
};
```

Comment: What exactly does it say? Which line? What's `arbBinar<T>`? Where is it declared?

Comment: Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<' c:\users\andrei\desktop\sda project\sda\sda\nodab.h 13 1 SDA

Comment: template<typename T>
class arbBinar{
protected:
 nodAB<T> *radacina;
public:
 arbBinar():radacina(0){}
 arbBinar(nodAB<T> *rad) {radacina=rad;}
 nodAB<T> *getRadacina(){return radacina;}
 ~arbBinar();
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you classes refer to each other in circular fashion. That would indicate that a forward declaration for at least one of the template classes should be required. More precisely, a forward declaration of `nodAB<T>` template is required before the definition of `arbBinar` template.

```
template<typename T> class nodAB;
```

Did you make that forward declaration?

Moreover, if these classes are declared in different header files, you might have an issue with circular header inclusion. Show us how are these declarations are distributed across files, and how you include these files into each other.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `arbBinar` is declared before `nodAB`.

Comment: @user1494130: That's *exactly* the issue. You have to declare `arbBinar` before `nodAB` and you have to declare `nodAB` before `arbBinar`. Which means that a forward declaration is absolutely required.

Comment: yeah , you're right , i have circular dependency , that's why it doesn't work . I have to make an abstract ordered list with an implementation in binary search treee